# Kibana shows The data you are seeing might be incomplete or wrong

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk

Configuring my elk stack => Kibana, elasticsearch and filebeat. All working fine but, when i wanted to view the logs on kibana, i recieved this error

1 of 8 shards failed
The data you are seeing might be incomplete or wrong.

```
See response:

    {
      "took": 332,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 9,
        "successful": 8,
        "skipped": 8,
        "failed": 1,
        "failures": [
          {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": ".apm-agent-configuration",
            "node": "_KJoEVfvT9W8-ezUwcdPlg",
            "reason": {
              "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason": "Trying to retrieve too many docvalue_fields. Must be less 
                than or equal to: [100] but was [136]. This limit can be set by 
                 changing the [index.max_docvalue_fields_search] index level 
                   setting."
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
      }
    }
```

Please, any idea to this?

Comment: Click on Inspect and copy/paste the response Kibana gets from ES.

Comment: Okay. let do that..

Comment: Please remove the comments, properly format the queries and update your question

Comment: @Val. updated the question. please, see.

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice to see the query as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved by changing the `index.max_docvalue_fields_search` setting for that index:

```
PUT .apm-agent-configuration/_settings
{
  "index.max_docvalue_fields_search": 200
}
```

Comment: You can run that in Kibana Dev Tools and then your query will magically work again

Comment: i got time out: {"statusCode":502,"error":"Bad Gateway","message":"Client request timeout"}

Comment: Weird... is your cluster overloaded? Try again?

Comment: done now @Val.. thank you very much. but I'd need your knowledge on Indexing logs for visualization on kibana.